# Interchange of expectations

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value

Let $f:\Re\rightarrow \Re $ and $g:\Re^2\rightarrow \Re$ be two functions and $p(X)$ and $q(Y)$ two probability distributions over two random variables $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Assuming that $\mathbb{E}_{p(X)}[f(\mathbb{E}_{q(Y)}[g(X,Y)])]$ is well defined, do you think it's correct the following statement?

``Let us define a function $h:\Re\rightarrow\Re$, such that $\mathbb{E}_{p(X)}[f(\mathbb{E}_{q(Y)}[g(X,Y)])]=\mathbb{E}_{q(Y)}[h(\mathbb{E}_{p(X)}[g(X,Y)])]$.''

I don't need to know the specific form of the function $h$. I only need to know if I can assume that this function $h$ is well defined.

Comment: I guess you made a mistake by writing $p(Y)$ in the right part of your equation. Also your identity seems false since by taking $f(x)=x^2$ $g(a,b)=a+b$ i think this is impossible to find any $h$. (Since you have $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ appearing at the left part and you cannot reproduce this by any $h$ in the right part. So the answer would be no.

Comment: You need to merge your accounts then you can edit your own questions.